# javascript nested function call in reactjs render classname

Tags: javascript, reactjs

function inside render statement is not working. How to call the function as part of className? `this._displayLogic().showATraffic()` is returning undefined.

**Expected result:** `classname ="up blue"`,

**Current result:** **"up "** and `an error in console.`

```
class LineStatus extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  _displayLogic=()=>{
    var showATraffic=()=>{
        return "blue";
    };
    var showBTraffic=()=>{
        return "Yellow";
    };

    console.log(showATraffic()+"....."); //this works.
  }

 componentWillMount(){
  this._displayLogic();
 }
  render(){
    return(
        <div className="status-content collapse" key={this.props.key}>
          <div className={"up "+this._displayLogic().showATraffic()}>
            <Row className="show-grid">
                <span>Approval</span>
            </Row>
            <Row className="status-subcontent collapse">
              Line content goes here.
            </Row>
          </div>
)
  }
}
```

Comment: did you paste the code correctly? seems like you are missing an ending </div> inside the render's funtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_displayLogic` should return an object when invoked e.g.

```
_displayLogic=()=>{
  var showATraffic = () => 'blue'
  var showBTraffic = () => 'Yellow'
  return {showATraffic, showBTraffic};
}
```